# What is an incoherent state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, terminology, density-operator, decoherence

I am reading through a recent [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.06474) which speaks frequently of "incoherent states" without ever defining what such a state is.  I gather from the context of the paper that it has something to do with the density matrix being diagonal in the energy eigenbasis, and it appears that this concept has nothing at all to do with the familiar notion of "coherent states" of e.g. a harmonic oscillator.  Could someone please provide a definition for this type of incoherent state?

Comment: Incoherent states are precisely defined on the bottom left of page 2, including a reference where I expect even more details can be found...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By an incoherent state (relatively to a basis, and it must be specified), they simply mean a mixed state described by a diagonal density matrix (in this basis).

The word "coherence" refers to the usual thing in the discussion of "decoherence" (indeed, it has no simple relationship with the coherent states of harmonic oscillators). Coherence is the characteristically quantum mechanical well-defined relative phase between two or many probability amplitudes. In the density matrix language, "coherence" is reflected by nonzero off-diagonal matrix elements ($\rho_{jk} = c^*_j c_k$ if the density matrix is calculated from a pure state) of the density matrix. The converse, i.e. the density matrix with vanishing off-diagonal elements, is therefore called "incoherent".

"Decoherence" is a process that drives the reduced density matrix for a physical system of interest towards the incoherent form – by interactions with the environment. The off-diagonal elements are just converging to zero.

Comment: One more clarification: In the paper they also make statements to the effect "the state is incoherent if and only if $\rho$ commutes with $H$", where the Hamiltonian $H$ provides the preferred basis you mention in your answer.   This is not equivalent to the statement "the state is incoherent if and only if $\rho$ is diagonal in the eigenbasis of $H$" when $H$ has degeneracies (e.g. if $H$ has only one eigenvalue it is proportional to the identity and commutes with everything).  I presume what they mean is that, for suitable eigenbasis, $\rho$ can be made diagonal (i.e. incoherent), correct?

Comment: I think so - or they may simply be sloppy about the degenerate case (or assuming that it doesn't happen).